# What are the under-the-hood differences between round() and numpy.round()?

Tags: python, numpy, rounding

Let's look at the ever-shocking round statement:

```
>>> round(2.675, 2)
2.67
```

I know why round "fails"; it's because of the binary representation of 2.675:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal(2.675)
Decimal('2.67499999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875')
```

What I do not understand is: **why does NumPy not fail**?

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.round(2.675, 2)
2.6800000000000002
```

### Thinking

Do not mind the extra zeros; it's an artefact from Python's printing internal rounding. If we look at the "exact" values, they're still different:

```
>>> decimal.Decimal(round(2.675, 2))
Decimal('2.6699999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875')

>>> decimal.Decimal(numpy.round(2.675, 2))
Decimal('2.680000000000000159872115546022541821002960205078125')
```

Why oh why does NumPy behave?

I thought at first that NumPy had to handle floats using extra bits, but:

```
>>> decimal.Decimal(numpy.float(2.675))
Decimal('2.67499999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875')
>>> decimal.Decimal(2.675)
Decimal('2.67499999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875')
# Twins!
```

What is happening behind the curtains? I looked a bit at NumPy's [round implementation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.8.0/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L2614), but I'm a Python newbie and I don't see anything overly fishy.

Comment: ["Results may also be surprising due to the inexact representation of decimal fractions in the IEEE floating point standard and **errors introduced when scaling by powers of ten**.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html) Strictly speaking, 2.67 is the better result. 2.68 is a rounding error.

Comment: I'm not an expert at the numpy or the python proper source code, but I think the numpy implementation is here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/7b2f20b406d27364c812f7a81a9c901afbd3600c/numpy/core/src/multiarray/calculation.c#L588 and the python implementation is here:  http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1f1498fe50e5/Objects/floatobject.c#l866

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One on top of the hood difference is documented:

In cases where you're halfway between numbers, [`np.round`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html) rounds to the nearest "even" number (after multiplying by `10**n` where `n` is the second argument to the respective `round` function) whereas the [builtin `round`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) rounds away from 0.

```
>>> np.round(2.685, 2)
2.6800000000000002
>>> round(2.685, 2)
2.69
```

Under the hood, you can get differences when using the scaling parameter.  Consider the differences between `round(2.675 * 10.**2)` and `round(2.675, 2)`.  This is certainly a result of the floating point math which as always has some rounding error associated with it.  To go any further we would really need to look at the real implementation.

Comment: What is n in this case?

Comment: @HankDitton -- Second argument to `round`.  Sorry, should have been more explicit.

Comment: Why does `np.round` round wrong in your case then - I thought it was the other way around, cf. the OP.

Comment: "Nearest even" and "away from zero" are the same in the OP's example.

Comment: @user2357112 -- That's a fair point.  When in doubt.  Blame floating point math :).  Consider the differences between `round(2.675 * 10.**2)` and `round(2.675, 2)`.  Clearly `round` isn't handling this exactly consistently likely because after multiplying by 100, the value is no longer exactly between the two values.

Comment: Thanks for the `10**n` clarification, I had trouble grasping the concept of "even" floats.